# Capture child window OK click in parent window- Cocoa/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I open child window from parent window using below code:

```
if (!loginWindow) {
        loginWindow = [[LoginController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"LoginWindow"];

    }

    [loginWindow showWindow:self];
```

What I want is, in the child window (loginWindow), If user clicks on OK button, I need to get the response in parent.

ex :

```
if ([loginWindow showWindow:self] == OK clicked) //THis is just algorithm
{
   //do something
}
```

How can we achieve this in Cocoa/Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You want to some change in a class by firing some action in other class then in this case use delegate method
if you know how to use delegate then make a delegate method otherwise follow this
 [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tip-create-your-own-objective-c-delegate-protocol/)

Comment: I have implemented delegate. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a delegate in the child view controller, set the delegate to be the parent view controller, and when the ok button is clicked, you call the delegate method.